# I can only start the MongoDB shell from its directory, but I can't do it globally

Tags: mongodb, express, command-line-interface

As documentation says, I have to write Mongo in my shell to run the Mongo shell. However, It won't work!

On the other hand, If I go to its directory (program-files/mongoDB/Server/4.4/Bin) and I type .\mongo , it opens and works!

Is there a way I can just use it from any directory? I am constantly moving across files to use it and it gets very annoying. I already tried to run npm i -g mongo and did nothing.

Thanks!!

[translated from Spanish:mongo: The term 'mongo' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program. Check if you entered the name correctly or, if you included a path, check that the path is correct
and try again.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3Xpb.png)

Comment: Well if you want to access  mongo globally you will need to setup the path in windows Environment  variable. Follow the below link to setup the path and you can start mongo from anywhere using cmd prompt. 
https://dangphongvanthanh.wordpress.com/2017/06/12/add-mongos-bin-folder-to-the-path-environment-variable/

Comment: Simply start `c:\program-files\mongoDB\Server\4.4\Bin\mongo.exe` or add this folder to your `PATH` environment variable. Maybe you mix the command line (`cmd`) with the power-shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add path for mongoDB in Environment variable. Visit below link to know more:

https://dangphongvanthanh.wordpress.com/2017/06/12/add-mongos-bin-folder-to-the-path-environment-variable/